# SRL vs Frame semantic parsing

Tags: nlp

I came across Frame Semantic Parsing [1]. As you probably know it “groups predicates in a hierarchy of structured concepts, known as *frames*[2]”, and each frame consists of several roles.

I want to ask you a couple of questions on this.

As I see, this is very similar to what SRL is doing with some slight differences. At some point in the paper it says:

“This task is most similar to the problem of semantic role labeling, but uses frame-speciﬁc labels that are richer than the PropBank annotations.”

How do you see these two?

Do you think frame-semantic annotation is richer?

Do you think one of these can be substitutes for another?

Which one do you think is a better abstraction ?

[1] http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~nasmith/papers/das+schneider+chen+smith.naacl10.pdf

[2] https://framenet2.icsi.berkeley.edu/fnReports/data/frameIndex.xml

Comment: did you forget the references? [1,2]?

Answer (score 1):

> “This task is most similar to the problem of semantic role labeling,
>   but uses frame-speciﬁc labels that are richer than the PropBank
>   annotations.”

Consider the following sentence:

> He bought a candy

Propbank uses thematic relations (He:agent, candy:theme), Framenet uses so called 'frame elements' (He:buyer, candy:goods).
So... yes, Framenet labels are richer, however you should have a look at SemLink which offers a mapping between Propbank and FrameNet (and VerbNet).